# How to solve for Key Error in Complex Nested Json

Tags: python, json, get, scrape

I keep receiving key error 'Notes'. Notes is in a nested response. How do I solve this? I have included a sample of the json.
Traceback added by request.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxxxxx/Documents/code/trade show w notes", line 16, in <module>
    target = "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s" % (contact["company_name"], contact["location"], contact["summary"], contact["job_title"], contact["name"], contact["job_industry"], contact["email"], contact["first_name"], contact["last_name"], contact["notes"])
KeyError: 'notes'
```

\

```
"data": [
    {
        "team_id": 53806,
        "name": "Nicholas Bancroft Cooke",
        "first_name": "Nicholas",

        ],
        "email": null,
        "metadata": null,
        "qualification": [
            {
                "qualification_id": 17573056,
                "qualification": "connected",

                "notes": null,
```

\\

```
     page = 1
     url = "https://teams-api.grip.events/1/team/53806/event/123721/member/236388/contact/inbound_lead/reviewed?page=1"
     headers = {
         'authorization': 'Bearer eaf3bd4b-6861-4ca2-a86e-3a96c73deac0',
}
data = ["company_name", "job_title", "name",  "job_industry", "summary", "notes", "location", "first_name", "last_name", "email"]
with open("list31.txt", "w", encoding='utf-8') as f: #added " encoding='utf-8' "
         for page in range(1, 1000):
             response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers).json()
             contacts = response["data"]
             for contact in contacts:
                 target = "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s" % (contact["company_name"], contact["location"], contact["summary"], contact["job_title"], contact["name"], contact["job_industry"], contact["email"], contact["first_name"], contact["last_name"], contact["notes"])
                 f.write(target + "\n")
                 print(target)
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: Added to the post.

Comment: The sample data isn't valid json.   There's an errant ```]``` after the ```first_name": "Nicholas",``` entry.   Also,  your "notes" key isn't in the ```contact``` entry, but in the ```contact["qualification"][0]``` dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the `notes` key which is under `qualification`.

Then it should be: `contact["qualification"][0]["notes"]`

Here `contact["qualification"]` is a list. if by any chance contact["qualification"] is an empty list it will raise an `IndexError`. you need to handle it with a `try-catch` or `if-clause`

Comment: This is very helpful! If I utilize [0] will that catch all that may be listed underneath?

Comment: @ToriElstrom. [0] accesses the first item in a list (if any or raises an error). I believe you have to read/practice about `list` and `dict` in python.